# MySQL select now()

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to get time from my database.

```
string result;
using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=database;Uid=root;Pwd='';"))
{
     string sql = "select now()";
     MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection);
     connection.Open();
     result = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
     connection.Close();
}
DateTime now = DateTime.ParseExact(result, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", null);
metroLabel4.Text = (newtime);
```

This is the code I'm using and when I build my program It gives error for `result = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();` this line.

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Comment: @SonerGönül http://prntscr.com/94f9nw

Comment: Can you please show it as a text?

Comment: @SonerGönül Isn't string is a text?

Comment: No, I mean, I can't see the image since I'm at work. Show the error message as a text in your question.

Comment: @SonerGönül It's a Turkish error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in DropSharp.exe

Additional information: 'System.DateTime' türündeki nesne 'System.String' türüne atılamadı."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like [MySQL `Now()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) returns date and time and this type mapped with `DateTime` in .NET side.

Since `ExecuteScalar` returns `object`, you can explicitly cast it to `DateTime` and it should be fine.

```
DateTime result;
...
result = (DateTime)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

A few things more;

- Use `using` statement to dispose your command as well.
- Since you use `using` statement, your `connection.Close()` line is unnecessary. That statement close your connection automatically.
- You don't need parsing anymore. Just assing `DateTime now = result;`
- It is not clear what is `newtime` exactly but after that, you can assign it as `metroLabel4.Text = now.ToString()` or whatever you format with `ToString(string)` overload.

Comment: Final code and working really fine http://prntscr.com/94fgol if anyone need it they can use it thanks for your help.